# How to stop countDownTimer when a variable reaches a certain value

Tags: android, countdowntimer

What I am trying to do basically is that I want my countDownTimer to run 60 times , i want to do this by setting the value of a variable to 0 and stopping the timer when the variiable reaches the value of 60.

```
    i=0;

       new CountDownTimer(3600000,60000) {

              public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    imageClock.setImageResource(image1stRec[i++]);
                }

              public void onFinish() {
               MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.alarm);
               mp.start();
                }

             }.start();
```

Comment: You want to run 60 times?

Comment: well the countdowntimer class is pretty straight forward... just put the desired amount of time in the first parameter and then in the 2nd parameter just write the first parameter divided by 60

Answer (score 0):

Below method help you to shecdule a countdown for 60 times

```
      new CountDownTimer(60000,1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                imageClock.setImageResource(image1stRec[i++]);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.alarm);
                 mp.start();
            }
         }.start();
```